# How to give the shade to the list item of particular index in the telerik mvc combo box

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-mvc

Code:

```
  @( Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
    .Name("cmbTest")
    .ClientEvents(events => events
                    .OnOpen("oncmbTestOpen")
                )
    )

   function oncmbTestOpen(e)
   {
        var index = 2;
        // How to give the shade(default orange color) to the list item of particular index(2) in the telerik mvc combo box
   }
```

How to give the shade(default orange color) to the list item of particular **index(2)** in the telerik mvc combo box when opening the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to a li element this way:

```
function oncmbTestOpen(e){
  var index = 2;
  var $li = $(this).data('tComboBox').dropDown.$items.eq(index);
  //$li.css('color', 'red');
}
```